# android - How to make gridView like this

Tags: android, android-gridview

I was wondering how can I make a gridView like this .As you can see in this image ,it's a very beautiful gridView but I don't know how can I make one .

[image]

is this a gridView or something else ?

Comment: search for staggered gridview in any major search engine. You will surely find many examples.

Comment: or you can just use cordova framework and make it with html css

Comment: https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

Answer (score 1):

For varying columns and rows in a GridView, you can use this library:-
https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

For writing text over images, use custom adapter with layout inflater.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Staggered gridview. Try any one of these libraries

- https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid
- https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView
- https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary
- https://github.com/bulletnoid/StaggeredGridView

Answer (score 0):

In the custom Adapter implement the following functions to create separate views

```
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
       return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position % 3;
    }
```